# Nullify pointer before returning the address

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

In the following code, for safety, I want to nullify the pointer before returning the address it stores. How can I do this?

```
int& foo (vector<int>& vec)
{
    double dis = 1e6;
    int* ptr = NULL;

    for (int& i: vec)
    {
        tmp = calculate (i);

        if (tmp < dis)
        {
            dis = tmp;
            ptr = &i;
        }
    }

    if (ptr != NULL)
    {
        // How to nullify the ptr?
        return *ptr;
    }
}
```

Comment: That looks horrible. If you describe what you want to do, maybe you can get a few suggestions how to write a better function.

Comment: My aim is to return the address of the integer which is chosen according to some condition. I return by reference because I need to use exactly the same integer later not a copy of it.

Comment: That smells like bad design. Why do you need to have the address of something stored in a vector?

Comment: Because I will modify it later and don't want to make a copy of it.

Comment: @Shibli Why not then store a `std::unique_ptr` to the object then?

Comment: It seems like you're implementing your own version of `std::min_element` with a custom predicate.

Comment: `I want to nullify the pointer before returning the address it stores` If you nullify the pointer, the address will be lost. Not sure what you trying to do here.

Comment: Do you want to always return `NULL`? That's pointless. Make your function returning `void` and forget about return value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should return an iterator to the position, not a pointer.
The validity duration of both the iterator and the pointer to the `int` would be the same.
That way you can also handle the case where no result is found, by returning the `vec.end()`.

```
vector<int>::iterator foo (vector<int>& vec)
{
    double dis = 1e6;
    auto result = vec.end();

    auto it_end = vec.end();
    for (auto it = vec.begin(); it != it_end; ++it)
    {
        const double tmp = calculate (*it);

        if (tmp < dis)
        {
            dis = tmp;
            result = it;
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Just in case, someone else mentioned `std::min_elment`.
This would not apply here, as `foo` calls `calculate` n-times, while `std::min_element` would call it 2*(n-1)-times.